# Is it possible to write any differentiable convex closed curve in the following way?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am wondering if is it possible to write "any" differentiable convex closed curve with this formula:
$$ c(\theta)=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        r(\theta)\cos(\theta) \\
        r(\theta)\sin(\theta) \\
        \end{bmatrix} +  \begin{bmatrix}
        a \\
        b \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $r:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb R $ differentiable and $a,b\in \mathbb R$.

Thanks for answers!

Edit: I added the vector $[a,b]^T \in \mathbb R^2$ as it needs to be independent of translation.

Comment: No that's all, sorry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

By translation, assume the origin is inside your curve and forget about $a$ and $b$. For every $\theta\in S^1$, take the ray going from the origin in the direction $\theta$. By convexity, this ray intersects your curve exactly once. Define $r(\theta)$ to be the magnitude of the point of intersection.

Comment: It's not obvious to me that $r$ is differentiable.

Comment: @MikeMiller It follows from convexity that all the rays are transverse to our curve. Now apply the inverse function theorem.